# increase font awesome icons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I'm having a bit trouble with some font-awesome icons. I'm trying to increase the size of a few of them, but for some reason nothing I seem to do works.

Here is my html

```
<div class="span5 bookBuild">
 <div class="well well-small">
   <h4>Build your Book!</h4>
   <div class="span2">
      <i class="icon-file icon-large"></i>
   </div><!--span2-->
   <div class="span9">
      <p>This is a paragraph</p>
    </div><!--span9-->
    <p class="clearfix"></p>
   </div><!--well-->
 </div><!--span5-->
```

and I have tried to add as you can see the `icon-large` class as well as the `icon-2x` class. None of the `icon-2x` - `icon-4x` are working.

I have also tried targeting the specific icon and then increasing the font size such as `font-size: 3em;`

Any help would be amazing!

Comment: can you share a fiddle?

Comment: @andrew I would, but I cannot get bootstrap to work within a fiddle. Even the ones I've googled are not working.

Comment: You can try bootply.com to provide a fiddle. you can easily embed fontawesome there.

Answer (score 18):

we can make some icon bigger using font awesome.  Font awesome provided a class to increse them.

To increase icon sizes relative to their container, use the fa-lg (33% increase), fa-2x, fa-3x, fa-4x, or fa-5x classes.

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/

Comment: u r using icon-2x,3x, 4x.... i suggest use fa-lg, fa-2x. use fa rather than icon. second thing is that only few icon we can make bigger. Not all.

Comment: This is an older version of font awesome, those classes did not exist yet...I was using the classes that did exist.

Comment: And yes, you can make all icon's larger,  have seen it done and since this project was able to do it using font-size.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me in bootstrap ONLY after I added `!important`, like this:

```
.fa-big{font-size: 100px !important;}
```

Comment: I just realized the reason I had to add !important was because I was linking my styles.css before the bootstrap css file.  Once I reversed it, my styles css had priority over the bootstrap css (I'm somewhat new at programming in HTML so I'm still learning all this).

Answer (score 2):

Use `icon-4x` instead of `icon-large`. See here: http://bootply.com/79841

Comment: I have already tried that. I just put a the icon-2x instead of 4x. Neither work.

Comment: working with it a bit kore, this actually makes my icons disappear completely.

Comment: Yes it does, but when I place the same code none of the icons react. They either disappear completely, stay the same or reveal every icon in the set.

Comment: @zazvorniki it might be a separate dependency added that's messing with it. Maybe you could paste the entire HTML on http://pastebin.com/.

Comment: Here is a chop of the html, I don't see anything that is messing with it, but then again I've been staring at this all day trying to figure out whats wrong.. http://chopapp.com/#o0r4bz5t

Comment: @zazvorniki Thanks. I can't see `font-awesome.css` loaded anywhere. You will need to add it after `bootstrap.css`.

Comment: hella funny. stumbled across this trying to add big icons to http://www.codeforafrica.org/

Comment: @ConnorLeech Lol. Quite.

Answer (score 2):

Font Awesome is a font so add a class and increase the font-size

```
 .fa-big{
    font-size: 100px;
 }


<i class="fa fa-ship fa-big"></i>
```

Comment: Notice that this question is not using bootstrap 3 nor the latest font awesome. This was asked two years ago and I had at the time tried adding the classes that were available 'icon-large' as stated above.

Comment: Maybe this answer will help someone else that doesn't know you can adjust font-awesome icons with font-size css.  I was very happy when I learned it.  :)